# vb.net - button.text not aligning when pulled from data table

Tags: sql, vb.net, string, button, alignment

Please refer to the images below:

[image: Button.Text Hardcoded]
[image: Button.Text from Database]

So the left image has a hardcoded string and the image on the right has the data pulled in form an MSSQL database.

The code below makes up these buttons (they are dynamically created based on the amount of records in the database table)

```
    'Button 
Private Sub LoadUseraccount()

    'Connect to Database (from module1)
    connectSQL()

    'Setup DataAdapter with query
    Dim da As SqlDataAdapter
    da = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * from useraccounts", SQLConn)

    'Store results in temporary datatable
    Dim dt As DataTable
    dt = New DataTable()

    da.Fill(dt)

    Dim i As Integer

    'Create a button for every record shown in useraccount table.
    For i = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
        Dim dr As DataRow = dt.Rows(i)
        Dim newbutton As New Windows.Forms.Button
        Dim dataString As String = CStr(dr.Item("username"))


        newbutton.Name = "btnButton" & i
        newbutton.Text = dataString '<========= This Line is where the button text is set
        newbutton.Top = 200 + i * 105
        newbutton.Left = 40

        newbutton.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter

        newbutton.Height = 107
        newbutton.Width = 180

        Dim myFont As System.Drawing.Font
        myFont = New System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 20.25)
        newbutton.Font = myFont
        newbutton.ForeColor = Color.White
        newbutton.BackColor = Color.MidnightBlue

        Me.Controls.Add(newbutton)
    Next

    SQLConn.Close()

End Sub
```

So the only difference in the images is what the text is set to display on the buttons, but the alignment is all out of whack when the string is not static.

What am I doing wrong or what am I missing to have the right image formatted the same as the left one?

Cheers :-)

Comment: It seems like your data from db contains a newline/carriagereturn. Try to add a Trim() to the `dataString`

Comment: brilliant :-) Post it as an answer if you want the points :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried your example and I was unable to reproduce the problem until I added a carriagereturn/linefeed to the variable used for button text.

So I assume that your data contains some unprintable characters that disalign your output.

A simple fix should be

```
newbutton.Text = dataString.Trim()
```